# Plotting a Histogram in Matlab with Descriptive Statistics

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is is possible to plot a histogram in MATLAB where the summary statistics are displayed in the histogram?

Here is an example of what I want generated in [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42948/histogram-plot-with-descriptive-statistics-on-the-plot)

[image]

[image]

I've looked on the web but can't find an example like this in MATLAB anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`text()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function to add anything you want to a plot in MATLAB.

Alternatively, you can use [`textbp()`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11466-textbp--text-with-legend-style--best--placement), as pointed out by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2732801/daniel). [`textbp()`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11466-textbp--text-with-legend-style--best--placement) will automatically choose the best position to place text.

Comment: or `textbp` from matlab file exchange (chooses position automatically)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I've added that to the answer.